# MKMapView in presentModalView black

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I have 2 uiviewcontroller
- first one is the rootviewcontroller
- second one is a UIViewController with a mapview inside (MyMap.m/MyMap.h)

My problem is that when I try to show my second view as modalview from the first view my mapview is completely black.

this is the viewdidload of my second view, i try to set as initial view and the mapview works:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.delegate =self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *zoomButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithTitle: @"Zoom"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
    target: self
    action:@selector(zoomIn:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *typeButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithTitle: @"Type"
     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
     target: self
     action:@selector(changeMapType:)];

    NSArray *buttons = [[NSArray alloc] 
                    initWithObjects:zoomButton, typeButton, nil];

    toolBar.items = buttons;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

    annotationCoord.latitude = 47.640071;
    annotationCoord.longitude = -122.129598;

    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
    annotationPoint.title = @"Microsoft";
    annotationPoint.subtitle = @"Microsoft's headquarters";
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint]; 
}
```

and this is my first view action

```
MyMap *map = [[MyMap alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:map animated:YES];
```

I don't know why my mapview is turning black when i launch it from first view and not when i launch it as initial view any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using stordboard? Did you set the class of the MyMap correctly in IB?

Comment: Have you set the view property of MyMap to an instance of MKMapView?